# Changing list of tuples into list of list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples (a) that i want to change to list of lists (b).

```
a = [('ad','as'),('bs','bt'),('cs','cr')]
b = [['ad','as'],['bs','bt'],['cs','cr']]
```

I tried the code below but it does not change anything. Am i missing something?

```
b = []
for element in a:
    b.append(list(element))
```

Comment: Your code is correct. `b` will be exactly as you want it to be. What is the problem?

Comment: *it does not change anything* how are you verifying this?

Comment: @TimCastelijns tried the code on a test code provided by my tutor

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a shorter solution like:

```
b = map(list,a)
```

This generates a new list by applying the `list` function to every single element of 'a'.

This map is equivalent to the relatively longer code using comprehension lists:

```
  b = [ list(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('ad','as'),('bs','bt'),('cs','cr')]
b = [[elem[0], elem[1]] for elem in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>a = [('ad','as'),('bs','bt'),('cs','cr')]
>>>b = [list(item) for item in a]
>>>b
[['ad', 'as'], ['bs', 'bt'], ['cs', 'cr']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [('ad','as'),('bs','bt'),('cs','cr')]
b = []
for element in a:
    b.append(list(element))
print(b)
```

shows that b is now the desired list of lists - so your code works fine...

AND: Of course it does not change anythin if you really define `b`as shown in your example because:

1. you first define bas desired
2. You create a new list (empty) and label it `b`
3. you fill this list with the desired values.

--> the new `b` is the same as the old `b` - therefore there are no visible changes even though your code works.

If you want to add the tuple elements a second time, just delete the `b = []` line.

Comment: Probably because this is the exact same code OP posted